# Erro no angular

Tags: java, angularjs, spring

> Request URL:http://127.0.0.1:8080/itcd-intranet-ui
>
> Request Method:GET
>
> Status Code:404 Not Found
>
> Remote Address:127.0.0.1:8080
>
> Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade

**[image: Response Headers]**

> view source
>
> Connection:keep-alive
>
> Content-Length:74
>
> Content-Type:text/html
>
> Date:Mon, 13 Nov 2017 17:37:44 GMT
>
> Server:WildFly/10
>
> X-Powered-By:Undertow/1

**Request Headers**

> view source
>
> Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
>
> Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
>
> Accept-Language:pt-BR,pt;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
>
> Cache-Control:max-age=0
>
> Connection:keep-alive
>
> Host:127.0.0.1:8080
>
> Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1
>
> User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)
>   AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.89
>   Safari/537.36

Conforme imagem:

A rota está assim:

```
if (config == undefined)
    var config = {};
config.routes = function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl : 'views/home.html',
        caseInsensitiveMatch : true,
        requiresAuthentication : false
    }).otherwise({
        // templateUrl: 'views/404.html',
        template : "<div>página não encontrada</div>",
    });
};
```

index.html está assim:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="desif-ui" >
<head>
<body layout="column">

<!--CONFIGS-->
<script src="config/routes.js"></script>

<!--ASSETS-->
<script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular-locale_pt-br.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular-touch.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
</body>
</head>
</html>
```

[image: Erro no angular]

[image: Retorno rest]

[image: Servidor Wildfly]

O projeto tem 4 subprojetos desif-api, aonde ficam os rest. desif-core, Ficam os modelos, dto, repositório e serviços. desif-ui, aonde fica o angular.

Comment: Me parece que a URL `http://127.0.0.1:8080/itcd-intranet-ui` esteja errada, e a correta seria `http://127.0.0.1:8080/desif-ui`.

Comment: Está assim mesmo: http://127.0.0.1:8080/desif-ui. A imagem está errada, mas eu tento assim: http://127.0.0.1:8080/desif-ui e não funciona.

Comment: O projeto está neste link: http://www.netsoft.eti.br/desif/desif.zip.